# Solving heapdump issue for webapplication(JSP+SPRING MVC+JPA-HIBERNATE)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, ibm-was

I have been supporting webapplication which uses JSP+SPRING MVC+JPA-HIBERNATE. Recently we have heapdump issue in WAS server.Now we need to change some code in the application to prevent the heapdump.Otherwise deployment team wont move it to live environment.
I have loaded heampdump files(.phd) in IBM heapanalyser where it i givig the list of leak suspects
[image]

I am keeping the same data in the image captuted in HeapAnalser below.
There are two leak supsects given by hep anlayser.

```
1)97.499.936 bytes (52,48 %) of Java heap is used by 6 instances of    
java/util/WeakHashMap$Entry   Contains an instance) of the leak suspect:
-com/ibm/ws/wswebcontainer/webapp/WebApp holding 22.950.680 bytes at   
0x822ac78

2)Responsible for 22.950.680 bytes (12,35 %) of Java heap
-Contained under array of java/util/WeakHashMap$Entry holding 97.499.936    
bytes at 0x145bb10
```

I dont know how  i have to proceed further on this issue and I need to modify the code from our end to avoid this issue.For that i need to find which classes of my application creating the above instances.Please  suggest me how to proceed on this issue.

Comment: I don't know the memory analyzer tool you are using, but it should be possible to drill down in both leak suspects to determine where they come from and what they hold.  That should lead you back to the code, normally.  Also, just as a test try disabling second level cache,.

Comment: We are using HIBRANTE 3.0

Comment: @fvu We are using IBM heap analyser.As we are using IBM Websphere server,it will generate .phd files whenever some heap dump occurs.We will load that file in IBM heapanalyser to check the leak supects.The second level is disabled by default.We havent enabled it in my appllication

Comment: I meant, I have no experience with that specific tool, but according to this intro https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W3b463571efc8_4f02_99af_3cbc0da42ddc/page/IBM%20HeapAnalyzer%20Information it has all the views available to allow you to zoom in on the suspects, to see what they actually contain and who holds them.  That should lead you back to the code that initially caused the issue. You should not limit yourself to the leak suspect page, that's just the starting point of your diagnosis in most cases.